BEP20 transfer and transferFrom behave differently and I am confused
I am using ethersjs 6.13.1 and using the usdt contract 0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955 on the bsc chain
Calling the contract transfer method with ethers works fine：

But when I call the transferFrom method of the contract through ethers, it is not normal (approval authorization was performed before the call)
I expected to transfer 0.1usdt through transferFrom, but the actual amount displayed was 4.3855bnb. This made me very confused. I was transferring usdt through the bsc usdt contract, so how did it become a transfer of bnb?

I called some contract methods to check, but only the transferFrom method of the contract was incorrect.
Below is my code：
// ethers init
export class Web3Service {
provider: BrowserProvider;
signer: JsonRpcSigner;
address: string;


constructor() {
    this.provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
    this.provider.getSigner().then(signer => {
        this.signer = signer;
        this.signer.getAddress().then((address: string) => {
            this.address = address
            console.log("address:", address)
        });
    });
}

getContract(readOnly: Boolean): Contract {
    if (readOnly) {
        return new ethers.Contract(USDT_ADDRESS,
            ["function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256)",
                "function allowance(address _owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256)"],
            this.provider)
    } else {
        return new ethers.Contract(USDT_ADDRESS,
            ["function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)",
                "function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)",
                "function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool)"],
            this.signer)
    }
}}


const  CUSTOM_ADDRESS=My other wallet address
// Approve
function usdtApprove() {
    const web3Service = new Web3Service();
    const contract: Contract = web3Service.getContract(false)
    const amount = parseEther('90000000000');
    contract.getFunction("approve").send(CUSTOM_ADDRESS, amount)
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(jsonToString(result));
    }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('usdtApprove error:’, error);
   });
}

// transferFrom
function transferFrom() {
    const web3Service = new Web3Service();
    const contract: Contract = web3Service.getContract(false)
    const amount = parseEther("0.1");
    // Unable to call estimated gas
    // const estimateGas = await 
  contract.getFunction("transferFrom").estimateGas(web3Service.address,CUSTOM_ADDRESS, amount);
    // console.log("estimateGas:", estimateGas)
    let overrides = {
        gasLimit: parseUnits('2', 'gwei'),
        gasPrice: parseUnits('1', 'gwei')
    };
    contract.getFunction("transferFrom").send(web3Service.address, CUSTOM_ADDRESS, amount, overrides)
        .then((result) => {
            setTransfer(jsonToString(result))
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('transferFrom error:', error);
    });
  }
   // transfer
   function transfer2() {
      const amount = parseEther("0.1");
      const contract: Contract = web3Service.getContract(false)
      const estimateGas = await contract.getFunction("transfer").estimateGas(CUSTOM_ADDRESS, amount);
      let overrides = {
        gasLimit: estimateGas,
        gasPrice: parseUnits('1', 'gwei')
      };
     contract.getFunction("transfer").send(CUSTOM_ADDRESS, amount, overrides)
    .then((result) => {
        setTransfer(jsonToString(result))
    }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('transfer error:’, error);
});


I'm not familiar with your code, but as I guess you're having problem with the value param. Transfer method is having the same issue but you may not notice. In the first image, you want to transfer 0.01 USDT, but the transaction include 0.01 BNB together.
Beside it, the way you're using ethers isn't common I think :-?, could you try:
contract.getFunction("transferFrom").send(...)
=> 
contract.transferFrom(...)

the send function seems like you're trying to send BNB to the contract instead of executing a function

I did not notice that the transfer had 0.01bnb attached to it, which was very strange. Normally I was just transferring 0.01usdt.
I originally called contract.transferFrom(...). I found that contract.getFunction("transferFrom").send(...), these two ways of writing have the same effect in ethers 6

It's really strange :-?, to attach Bnb you need 2 conditions: abi function is payable, and the function include {value: bnbValue}. Could you share your repo?

I have uploaded the complete code to GitHub, here is the link https://github.com/liuchengts/web3-app . To run it, click the transfer button or transferFrom button (you need to first approve the transaction using the usdtApprove button to reproduce the above issue)
